# LDAP schema catalog and url attribute type

Tags: ldap, schema, custom-attributes

I'm looking for one attribute in order to store an url string like a homepage...

By other side, I'm looking for creating a attribute type in order to store some specific values like (single | married).

And the last question is about, how on earth can I find a ldap schema repository in order to re-use them?

Thanks for all.

---

Sorry, I'm using openldap 2.4.
Thanks.

Comment: Which LDAP server are you talking about? Active Directory?

Comment: Google works well for some of this. I found "sunIdentityServerPPLegalIdentityMaritalStatus" defined for AD:https://github.com/OpenRock/OpenAM/blob/master/openam/openam-federation/OpenFM/src/main/ldif/fam_ad_schema.ldif